# Return rows in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to develop an application in ASP.NET with blogs and categories in two languages. One of the functionalities is returning the name of a category in a particular language.

Not all categories have two languages. Some have English, others have Italian, others have both. Here's the function that performs the select I was talking about.

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(250)

IF EXISTS(SELECT Name = Coalesce(BlogCategoryTranslation.Name, ' ')
          FROM BlogCategoryTranslation 
          WHERE BlogCategoryID = @CategoryID AND LanguageID = @LanguageID)
BEGIN   
    SET @Name = (SELECT Name
                 FROM BlogCategoryTranslation 
                 WHERE BlogCategoryID = @CategoryID 
                   AND LanguageID = @LanguageID)    
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Name = (SELECT TOP 1 Name 
                 FROM BlogCategoryTranslation 
                 WHERE BlogCategoryID = @CategoryID 
                   AND LanguageID = @LanguageID);
END

RETURN @Name
```

Below there is a stored procedure that returns the category name for a given language. What I want is to always return a category. If it doesn't exist in a particular language, I want to display the record in the other language.

Is this possible and if it is, what would be the suggestions in order to do that?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BlogCategoryLanguage]
    @BlogCategoryID INT,
    @LanguageID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        BlogCategoryID AS 'CategoryID',
        Language.Name AS 'Language',
        dbo.BlogNameCategoryByLanguage(1,1) as 'Name',
        dbo.Blog_PublishedInCategory(1,BlogCategory.ID) AS 'Published'
    FROM 
        BlogCategoryTranslation
    INNER JOIN 
        BlogCategory ON BlogCategory.ID = BlogCategoryTranslation.BlogCategoryID
    INNER JOIN 
        Language ON Language.ID = BlogCategoryTranslation.LanguageID
    WHERE 
        BlogCategoryID = 1
END
```

I would really appreciate a few tips. It's the first time I have posted a question here and I'm not quite sure how this works. If this is a repost somehow,sorry about that.

Comment: Would I be correct in summarizing that the code in the first block represents the code of `BlogNameCategoryByLanguage` and that represents the problem? If so, the easiest way is to skip the check, and do a top 1 on the set ordered first on being the right language. A second order by would probably be preferable as well, e.g. on default language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the first block represents the function  `ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BlogNameCategoryByLanguage] (@CategoryID INT, @LanguageID INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(250)`. You're suggesting that I could select the correct language first. And how do I display the row if the language doesn''t correspond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` based `ORDER BY` with `TOP 1` like this.

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN LanguageID = @LanguageID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC` will give preference to the language with `LanguageID = @LanguageID`. If that Language is not available for the current `@Category`, it will pick a random language available for that category.

Something like this.

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(250)
SELECT @Name = TOP 1 Name
FROM BlogCategoryTranslation
WHERE BlogCategoryID = @CategoryID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LanguageID = @LanguageID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC;

RETURN @Name
```

**EDIT**

You can use the same `ORDER BY` and `TOP 1` in your main stored procedure like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    BlogCategoryID AS 'CategoryID',
    Language.Name AS 'Language',
    dbo.BlogNameCategoryByLanguage(1,1) as 'Name',
    dbo.Blog_PublishedInCategory(1,BlogCategory.ID) AS 'Published'
FROM 
    BlogCategoryTranslation
INNER JOIN 
    BlogCategory ON BlogCategory.ID = BlogCategoryTranslation.BlogCategoryID
INNER JOIN 
    Language ON Language.ID = BlogCategoryTranslation.LanguageID
WHERE 
    BlogCategoryID = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Language.LanguageID = @LanguageID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ughai. Say we have a category on both languages, the procedure returns both entries for that, even if I mentioned `SET @Name = (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM BlogCategoryTranslation
     WHERE BlogCategoryID = @CategoryID

    ORDER BY CASE WHEN LanguageID = @LanguageID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC);` How do I select only one of the results?

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. It actually does exactly that. This is great.